# How can i authenticate to the bucket using hmac keys via command line

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, gsutil

Need to move from use of minio client to a docker image having gcloud/gsutil and mysql images.

What i have currently:

1. /tmp/mc alias set gcs1 https://storage.googleapis.com $ACCESS_KEY $SECRET_KEY
2. mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --triggers --routines --events   --set-gtid-purged=OFF --single-transaction --host=$PXC_SERVICE -u root --all-databases | /tmp/mc pipe gcs1/mysql-test-dr/mdmpdb10.sql

What i need to change to:
3. <something similar to line no.1 (authorization)>
4. mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --triggers --routines --events   --set-gtid-purged=OFF --single-transaction --host=$PXC_SERVICE -u root --all-databases --skip-add-locks > $FILE_NAME && gsutil cp $FILE_NAME gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$FILE_NAME

Is there any replacement in gcloud/gsutil for the line no.1?
I was able to find gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=[KEY_FILE]
But that would be the service account key. I need to authenticate to the bucket using hmac keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to generate a boto configuration file using `gsutil config -a`. If you also have gcloud auth credentials configured, you may have to tell gcloud to not pass those (non-HMAC) credentials to gsutil, as gsutil may not allow you to have multiple credential types active at once. You can do this by running this gcloud command:

```
gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false
```

This is all mentioned in the `gsutil config` docs page: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config